# Take the derivative of the norm? can I do this?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Here is a quick question to the math community.

Is it possible to take the derivative of the euclidean norm?

For example,

if $f(x)=\|x\|$ then $f'(x)= \|1\|=1$ and $f''(x)=0.$

I know it is possible to take the derivative of the absolute function, provided you stay away from the point where the cusp occurs, so does the norm function have a similar caveat?

Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: If you are in $\mathbb R$ yes, otherwise the derivative of a function in $\mathbb R^n$ for $n\geq 2$ has no sense.

Comment: It depends what you mean by the "derivative" of a function $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$.  Perhaps you want the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient).  Or, perhaps you want a [partial derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments and other answers, the concept of derivative-on its own-of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ with respect to a vector does not exist. (Disclaimer: this is aside from terminological discussions on whether the term derivative includes extensions such as the Fréchet derivative, that maybe some of us would instead called differential. In the rest of this answer I stick to the usage of the term derivative restricted to functions of one real variable.)

However, you could consider a vector $x(t)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ that depends on a variable $t$, i.e. a function $x:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, the norm of $x(t)$ is a real function $f(t)=\|x(t)\|$ of one real variable and you could compute its derivative. Since Leibniz's rule is valid for the dot product, we have:
$$f'(t)=\frac{d \|x(t)\|}{dt}=\frac{d \sqrt{x(t) \cdot x(t)}}{dt}=
\frac{x(t) \cdot x'(t)}{\|x(t)\|}$$

Comment: I disagree with your first sentence though, the Frechet derivative is a standard way to generalize the idea of derivative to higher dimensional settings.

Answer (score 0):

A **derivative** is only a standardly defined concept used for functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

In that case, $f(x)=\|x\|$ is simply $|x|$, and the derivative of $f$ is not equal to $1$, it is equal to $1$ for $x>0$, to $-1$ for $x<0$, and it is undefined for $x=0$.

---

When speaking about functions $f$ from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$, things get complicated. We have concepts known as **partial derivatives**, which are sort of like regular derivatives of one dimensional functions.

We also have a concept known as a *differential*, which is defined (at a point $x_0$) as the linear function that best fits the behavior of $f$ around $x_0$.

In the case when $m=1$ (as is your case), the differentials of a function are also known as **gradients** and are basically just collections of all possible partial derivatives of $f$.

---

Bottom line: Neither gradients nor partial derivatives are all equal to $1$ for the case of $f(x)=\|x\|$.

Comment: Am I missing something in this answer? As far as I understand it, derivatives are NOT limited to functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The derivative of a map $f\colon \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ (if it exists) at a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the unique linear map $L$ such that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|f(x+h)-f(x) - L(h)|}{|h|} = 0$. Spivak's ''Calculus on Manifolds'' has more on this.

Comment: But I think it's pretty standard to speak of the derivative of a function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m $.

Comment: @AlexWertheim As far as I know, that's called a *differential*, not a *derivative*. English is not my first language, so I may be mistaken, but in my language, we have derivatives and we have differentials of functions, and they only sort of coincide when $f$ maps from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @5xum: fair enough, I was not trying to be rude or insensitive, so please forgive me if I was. Nevertheless, I find it misleading to say that one is limited to speaking of partial derivatives and gradients, so maybe you might consider amending that portion of your answer.

Comment: @AlexWertheim You were in no way rude or insensitive. You gave a fair comment to my answer.

Comment: I would say the [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) is a derivative...